# Alert array index and value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this loop:

```
for(k=0;k<colNames.length;k++){
    alert(colNames[k]);
}
```

Right now, it just alerts the user of the values in the array. How can I alert them of the index AND the value of each element in that array?

Comment: Here is a good introduction to JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: [Learn JS #1](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info), [a few helpful videos](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/conversation/learn-javascript-videos), [more information can be obtained here](http://javascript.info/). There, research materials. Now you can 'FastTrack' your learning. *returns to dungeon to play with dragons*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
for(k=0;k<colNames.length;k++){
    alert("Index: " + k + " value: " + colNames[k]);
}
```

Comment: And it was showing 2 secs difference for me. `:P` +1

Comment: I still prefer the index before the value, but that's just my sense of "organizeness".

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yup, didn't thought of that, editing :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
for(k=0;k<colNames.length;k++){
    alert("Index: " + k + " Value: " + colNames[k]);
}
```

Also use `console.log("Index: " + k + " Value: " + colNames[k]);`

Its less annoying

Answer (score 0):

You would not do this, because it's annoying to spam the user with dozens of popups they can't close. You would batch it like so, and output it to the DOM (or if it's for yourself, use `console.log`):

```
alert(JSON.stringify( colNames.map(function(x,i){return [i,x]}) ))
```

If you wanted to use something like console.log and output to multiple lines, you would do this, much cleaner than a for loop:

```
colNames.forEach(function(x,i){
    console.log(i,x);
})
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that `forEach` it's not completely cross-browser

Comment: @Nicosunshine: that is not correct, it is completely cross-browser http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: hehe I meant it doesn't work in IE7 or IE8, my bad